# JQuery form validation if statements don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I build a small form validator in JQuery. Now I have a problem with the output.

```
 $(function () {
     $('.register').submit(function (event) {
         $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
         $('.help-form').remove();
         var lengthp = $('input[name=password]').val().length;
         //alert(length);
         var error = new String();
         if ($('input[name=password2]').val() != $('input[name=password]').val()) {
             error['pwd'] = "Die Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!";
         }
         if (lengthp < 7) {
             error['length'] = "Das Passwort muss mindestens 8 Zeichen lang sein.";
         }
         if (error) {
             // add the error class to show red input
             if (error['pwd']) {
                 $('#passgroup2').addClass('has-error');
                 $("#passgroup2 > div").append('<span class="help-block help-form">' + error['pwd'] + '</span>');
             }
             if (error['length']) {
                 $('#passgroup').addClass('has-error');
                 $("#passgroup > div").append('<span class="help-block help-form">' + error['length'] + '</span>');
             }
         }
         //alert($('input[name=password]').val()));
         event.preventDefault();
     });

 });
```

The if statement `if (error['pwd']) {` works fine, but the statement `if (error['length']) {` isn't working.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it? 
Thank you!!!

Comment: `var error` has to be `object` right ?

Comment: I don't know why `if (error['pwd'])` works... Why you using `String` as array? Sting is a text (Array of characters), but not array for data. Use `var error = []` or `var error = {}` instead.

Comment: Thank you the answer of @Guillermo is working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following modifications to your code, if error is an object, the things will work easier, and the code will be more understandable, I'm not sure why you were making error to be a string. Hope it helps.

```
  //Error object
  var error = {};

 if ($('input[name=password2]').val() != $('input[name=password]').val()) {    
    //setting pwd error property 
    error.pwd = "Die Passwörter stimmen nicht überein!";
 }

 if (lengthp < 7) {
    //setting length error property  
    error.length = "Das Passwort muss mindestens 8 Zeichen lang sein.";
 }

 //Getting rid of this if because as it is defined, it will be always truthy 
 //if (error) {
    // add the error class to show red input
    if (typeof error.pwd !== "undefined") {
       $('#passgroup2').addClass('has-error');
       $("#passgroup2 > div").append('<span class="help-block help-form">' + error['pwd'] + '</span>');
    }

    if (typeof error.length !== "undefined") {
       $('#passgroup').addClass('has-error');
       $("#passgroup > div").append('<span class="help-block help-form">' + error['length'] + '</span>');
    }
 //}
```